# How do I display Angular Lint output in Jenkins using Junit?

Tags: jenkins, junit, angular-cli, lint, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

How do I display "npm lint" results in Jenkins?  I know how to display "pytest" results in Jenkins:

1. Run pytest like this: `pytest --junitxml=./path/to/pytestFile.xml ./path/to/code`
2. Run this Jenkins command: `junit testResults: "./path/to/pytestFile.xml"`

Once I do this, my test results appear in a "Test Results" window in Jenkins.  I want to do something similar with my angular lint results.  I tried doing this, but it didn't work:

1. Run linter like this: `npm lint --junitxml=./path/to/lintFile.xml`
2. Run this Jenkins command: `junit testResults: "./path/to/lintFile.xml"`

The problem is that npm doesn't have a --junitxml switch.  How can I do this?  I'm using the Jenkins declarative pipeline.

Comment: I eventually figured it out.  I run this lint command `tslint --project tsconfig.json -c tslint.json 'src/**/*.ts' --format junit --out lint-results.xml` and then run this to display the results in Jenkins `junit allowEmptyResults: true, testResults:  "lint-results.xml"`

Comment: Why are you trying to use a test result format for style results?

Comment: @OrangeDog, I don't understand your question.  Do you have some other solution in mind?

Answer (score 6):

JUnit is a format for test results, not lint results. It makes no sense to try to use it.

The best plugin to use is [Warnings Next Generation](https://plugins.jenkins.io/warnings-ng). It lists `tslint` as a supported format.

```groovy
steps {
  sh 'npm run-script --silent -- ng lint --format=checkstyle >checkstyle-result.xml'
}
post {
  always {
    recordIssues tool: tsLint(pattern: 'checkstyle-result.xml'),
                 enableForFailure: true
  }
}
```

If there are multiple projects in your workspace, you may be affected by [#14659](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/14659). Either specify a single project or pipe the output through [`split -l 1`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/split.1.html).

As you can see, you then get a report specifically for TSLint, separate from other analysis issues and test results. It also understands the different severity levels, which cannot be expressed with JUnit.

[image: generated graphs for TSLint, Test Results and Vulnerabilities]

Comment: What's the benefit of using this vs the solution I have in my comment above that I know already works and doesn't require an additional plugin?

Comment: @user2023861 because you get a report format that actually makes sense, and you can use the proper `ng lint`

Comment: I need a stronger reason than that to make this change.  Maybe other people will find this useful, but I won't go through the effort to make this change just to get something that I already have.

Comment: @user2023861 you also won't confuse them with your actual test results. The expected test count doesn't fluctuate based on the number of warnings. It can understand the different severity levels. It will track the lines and blame properly (not sure how that'd would be expressed in JUnit).

Comment: I run the lint and test results in different steps in the Jenkins job, so they already appear separately.  And if I want to ignore certain warnings, I can disable them using the lint rules or comments in the code that the linter understands.  There's no confusion.

Comment: +1 this solution for actually using `ng lint`, as opposed to the obstinate OP's solution to use `tslint` directly. This actually answers the question. OPs solution answers a different question.

Comment: @DerekWhite if following the YAGNI priciniple makes me obstinate, I guess I'm obstinate.